# Recursive Compound structure

Tags: c++, recursive-datastructures

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
template<class KeyType, class... Types>
class BasicCompound
    {
    public:
        using mapped_type = std::variant
            <
              ValueWrapper<BasicCompound>
            , ValueWrapper<Types>...
            >;

        using key_type = KeyType;

       // Accessors for retreiving and modifying content
       // ...

    private:
        std::map<key_type, mapped_type> m_content;
    };
```

`ValueWrapper` decides to put the content either inline or in a `std::unique_ptr`. Would it be possible with a similar interface, possibly through some kind of proxy, to make the recursiveness optional? By optional I mean that the user should not automatically get the possibility to store the `BasicCompound` inside itself, but rather specify it in the list of types.

What I have thought of:

1. A `using` directive does not work. A new type cannot be defined in it self, and a predeclaration of a following typedef is not allowed.
2. Adding a `bool` to the list of types, and use `std::conditional_t` for `mapped_type`. However, if the user wants to store an `X<BasicCompound>`, this approach fails.
3. Inject `mapped_type` from outside. Then I cannot hide the use of the `ValueWrapper` thing.
4. Using inheritance over a `typdef` like

   ```
   struct MyCompound : BasicCompound<std::string, MyCompound, int> {};
   ```

   This works but then the structure is not strictly recursive, as `MyCompound` now is a different type from `BasicCompound`. Maybe a CRTP-like approach could solve that problem, but then the inner compound type must be treated differently than the other types.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have use a specialization of a class template as one of the template arguments of that specialization; there's no way to write it, and its name would be infinitely long.  You can, however, use a wrapper to hold the recursive type:

```
template<class> class MaybeRecursive;

template<class T>
struct Wrapper {
  using type=T;
};
struct MRWrapper {
  using type=MaybeRecursive<MRWrapper>;
};

template<class T>
struct MaybeRecursive {
  using type=typename T::type;
  type *child;
};

void f() {
  int x;
  MaybeRecursive<Wrapper<int>> nonrec={&x};
  MRWrapper::type rec={&rec};
}
```

`MRWrapper` can be made a class template to provide additional template arguments to `MaybeRecursive`.

Comment: I guess that this is very similar to my option (3) in terms of usage: I cannot use the content directly, but must go through the wrapper type.

Comment: @user877329: You _can't_ write `X<X<...>,Y>` where the `...` makes the template argument equivalent to the outer type.  Nor can you write `X<A,Y>` where `A` is an alias for `X<A,Y>`.  This is (implementation guidance for) the closest you can get.